# Can we draw poly-lines in Venn diagram?

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

Can we draw poly-lines(for each circle) across the circles using d3.?
Here we have created the Venn diagram for a particular data set and I am not sure about how to create those poly-lines for each and every circle.

```html
<!doctype html>
        <head>
    
            <title>Audience Comparison</title>
    
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
            <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://rawgit.com/benfred/venn.js/master/venn.js"></script>
    
                <style>
                    body {
                        font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
                        font-weight: 700;
                        font-size : 14px;
                        margin: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
    }
    
                   .venntooltip {
                        font-size : 14px;
                        position: absolute;
                        text-align: center;
                        width: 128px;
                        height: 85px;
                        background: #333;
                        color: #fff;
                        padding: 2px;  
                        border: 0px;
                        border-radius: 8px;
                        opacity: 0;
                    }
    
    
                </style>
    
    
    
        </head>
    
    <body>
    
       
    <div id="container">
       <h1>Audience Comparison</h1>
       <p>Venn Diagram created with Ben Federickson's "<a href="http://www.benfrederickson.com/better-venn-diagrams/">A Better Algorithm for Area Proportional Venn and Euler Diagrams</a>"</p>
    
        <div id="venn_one" style=float:left>    
            <h3>Audience One</h3> 
        </div> 
      
    
        <div id="venn_two" style=float:left> 
            <h3>Audience Two</h3>
        </div>
    
    
    
    
    
        <script>
            var sets = [
                        {sets:["Audio"], figure: 8.91, label: "Audio", size: 8.91},
                        {sets:["Direct Buy"], figure: 34.53, label: "Direct Buy", size: 34.53},
                        {sets:["Branded Takeover"], figure: 40.9, label: "Branded Takeover", size: 40.9},
                        {sets: ["Audio", "Direct Buy"], figure: 5.05, label: "Audio and Direct Buy", size: 5.05},
                        {sets: ["Audio", "Branded Takeover"], figure: 3.65, label: "Audio and Branded Takeover", size: 3.65},
                        {sets: ["Direct Buy", "Branded Takeover"], figure: 4.08, label: "Direct Buy and Branded Takeover", size: 4.08},
                        {sets: ["Audio", "Direct Buy", "Branded Takeover"], figure: 2.8, label: "Audio, Direct Buy, and Branded Takeover", size: 2.8}
                        ];
    
    
            var chart = venn.VennDiagram()
                .width(500)
                .height(400)
    
              
    
            var div = d3.select("#venn_one").datum(sets).call(chart);
                div.selectAll("text").style("fill", "white");
                div.selectAll(".venn-circle path")
                        .style("fill-opacity", .8)
                        .style("stroke-width", 1)
                        .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
                        .style("stroke", "fff");
    
    
    
            var tooltip = d3.select("#venn_one").append("div")
                .attr("class", "venntooltip");
    
    
            div.selectAll("g")
                .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
                    // sort all the areas relative to the current item
                    venn.sortAreas(div, d);
    
                    // Display a tooltip with the current size
                    tooltip.transition().duration(40).style("opacity", 1);
                    tooltip.text(d.size + "% of Audience One saw " + d.label);
    
                    // highlight the current path
                    // highlight the current path
                    var selection = d3.select(this).transition("tooltip").duration(400);
                    selection.select("path")
                        .style("stroke-width", 3)
                        .style("fill-opacity", d.sets.length == 1 ? .8 : 0)
                        .style("stroke-opacity", 1);
                })
    
                .on("mousemove", function() {
                    tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                           .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
                })
    
                .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
                    tooltip.transition().duration(2000).style("opacity", 0);
                    var selection = d3.select(this).transition("tooltip").duration(400);
                    selection.select("path")
                        .style("stroke-width", 3)
                        .style("fill-opacity", d.sets.length == 1 ? .8 : 0)
                        .style("stroke-opacity", 1);
                });
    
    
    
      
    
    
            var sets = [
                        {sets:["Audio"], figure: 27.92, label: "Audio", size: 27.92},
                        {sets:["Direct Buy"], figure: 55.28, label: "Direct Buy", size: 55.28},
                        {sets:["Branded Takeover"], figure: 7.62, label: "Branded Takeover", size: 7.62},
                        {sets: ["Audio", "Direct Buy"], figure: 3.03, label: "Audio and Direct Buy", size: 3.03},
                        {sets: ["Audio", "Branded Takeover"], figure: 1.66, label: "Audio and Branded Takeover", size: 1.66},
                        {sets: ["Direct Buy", "Branded Takeover"], figure: 2.40, label: "Direct Buy and Branded Takeover", size: 2.40},
                        {sets: ["Audio", "Direct Buy", "Branded Takeover"], figure: 1.08, label: "Audio, Direct Buy, and Branded Takeover", size: 1.08} 
                        ];
    
    
        
            var chart = venn.VennDiagram()
                .width(500)
                .height(400)
    
              
    
            var div2 = d3.select("#venn_two").datum(sets).call(chart);
                div2.selectAll("text").style("fill", "white");
                div2.selectAll(".venn-circle path")
                        .style("fill-opacity", .8)
                        .style("stroke-width", 1)
                        .style("stroke-opacity", 1)
                        .style("stroke", "fff");
    
    
    
            var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
                .attr("class", "venntooltip");
    
    
    
    
            div2.selectAll("g")
                .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
                    // sort all the areas relative to the current item
                    venn.sortAreas(div2, d);
    
                    // Display a tooltip with the current size
                    tooltip.transition().duration(40).style("opacity", 1);
                    tooltip.text(d.size + "% of Audience Two saw " + d.label);
    
                    // highlight the current path
                    var selection = d3.select(this).transition("tooltip").duration(400);
                    selection.select("path")
                        .style("stroke-width", 3)
                        .style("fill-opacity", d.sets.length == 1 ? .8 : 0)
                        .style("stroke-opacity", 1);
                })
    
                .on("mousemove", function() {
                    tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                           .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
                })
    
                .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
                    tooltip.transition().duration(2500).style("opacity", 0);
                    var selection = d3.select(this).transition("tooltip").duration(400);
                    selection.select("path")
                        .style("stroke-width", 3)
                        .style("fill-opacity", d.sets.length == 1 ? .8 : 0)
                        .style("stroke-opacity", 1);
                });
    
    
    
        </script>
    
    </div> 
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

**Just like the poly-lines in the below donut chart (image).**
[image]

I am showing this donut chart so that you can get idea of poly-lines.
how can we create the same for each circle.